# I can't manage to override width styling in CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been building up this website in my free time. I've come across a slight problem. I assigned a width to my container, but can't happen to override it for my navbar (i want to assign a different bg colour to my navbar and make it take up 100% of my page. Here's my code. Thanks!! ;)

Code :

```
 #container{
  line-height: 1.6em;
  font-family:Georgia,serif;
  width: 70%;
  margin:auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}


#nav{
  width: 100% !important;
  background:#212121;
}
```

Comment: post your html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you set a parent width with 70%, every single child set as "width: 100%" will make it 100% but for parent attribute you set up, so it will be 70%. For example, in the same case if you set any other child "width: 50%" his width will actually be 50% of parent, which is 35% of your screen/viewport.

Comment: so actually to make it work try to locate your #nav outside of #container

Answer (score 0):

`70% of conianter = 100% for nav`

Basically, you are giving your container `width: 70%` which is only available space to all inner HTML elements inside the container.

so for nav this 70% conianter = 100% for nav.

The solution would make your nav `position: absolute` which will be in relation to the body(`position: relative`) and not your container div.

```css
 #container{
  line-height: 1.6em;
  font-family: Georgia,serif;
  width: 70%;
  margin:auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height:100vh;
}


#nav{
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:#212121;
  color: white;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height:1.3;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

body{
  position: relative;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

span{
  margin: auto 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <nav id="nav">
      <span>nav1</span>
      <span>nav2</span>
      <span>nav3</span>
      <span>nav4</span>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easier

```css
 #container{
  line-height: 1.6em;
  font-family: Georgia,serif;
  width: 70%;
  margin:auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height:100vh;
}


#nav{
  background:#212121;
  color: white;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height:1.3;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

span{
  margin: auto 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <span>nav1</span>
  <span>nav2</span>
  <span>nav3</span>
  <span>nav4</span></nav>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

solution would be to move your nav outside the container if possible.